# Request an action from httpModule

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, httpmodule

I want to request an action in specific controller from an HttpModule, and in action do same database operation and then return a Boolean value to detect that operation completed Successfully or not.

How can do it in?

Comment: Just curious, what you are trying to do ? There might be a better way.

Comment: @Shyju the scenario is: in beginRequest of httpmodule, I want to call an action to for adding user to database. then use those data to counting users visited site and so on...